# Easier way to scale assets for various iPhone sizes?

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit

When creating apps, is there any easier way to scale images, aside from creating and loading different assets based on the detected device?  It just seems kind of ridiculous to have to go through the pain of creating different images for iPhone 6+, 6, 5, 4, and also tweaking various positioning on the screen based on the device.

Also, I'm using Spritekit particle effects, and those have to be re-created too for different devices.

I know you can just have Xcode upscale iPhone 5 assets, but obviously the trade-off is image sharpness.  It would be nice if you could just design everything for the largest iPhone, and have it scale down automatically for other devices.  There isn't such a way, is there?

Comment: Not really. Consider that a full-resolution texture consumes a lot of memory, but the older the device the fewer memory is available. So while you can just scale down the highest-resolution image on older devices, there's a good chance the older version devices won't even be able to run the app due to high memory usage, or because they can't handle textures that big.

Answer (score 0):

define a micro in ViewController.m file

```
#define IS_WIDESCREEN ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
```

invoke below method

now see the code below this method work fine for every iPad device if you have aspect ratio of 1024*768 but little bit squashed for iPhone5 ,5s,6,6+  but this method is the fastest way to create game for all your device because its squashed SKScene based on screen ratio.

```
-(void)addAspect
{

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {

        if (IS_WIDESCREEN) {

            _globalscaleX=(1024.0f*2)/(568*2);
            _globalscaleY=(768.0f*2)/(320*2);

            LoaderScreen = [loadingScene sceneWithSize:CGSizeMake(_yourSKView.bounds.size.width*_globalscaleX, _yourSKView.bounds.size.height*_globalscaleY)];
              //LoaderScreen.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFit;
            LoaderScreen.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeFill;


        } else {


            if([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height==480)
            {

                _globalscaleX=(1024.0f*2)/(480*2);
                _globalscaleY=(768.0f*2)/(320*2);
            }
            else
            {
                _globalscaleX=(1024.0f*2)/(568*2);
                _globalscaleY=(768.0f*2)/(320*2);
            }


            LoaderScreen = [loadingScene sceneWithSize:CGSizeMake(_yourSKView.bounds.size.width*_globalscaleX, __yourSKView.bounds.size.height*_globalscaleY)];
              LoaderScreen.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeFill;
        }

    } else {

        _deviceType=ipad;
        _globalscaleX=1.0f;
        _globalscaleY=1.0f;

        LoaderScreen = [loadingScene sceneWithSize:CGSizeMake(_yourSKView.bounds.size.width, _yourSKView.bounds.size.height)];
        LoaderScreen.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
    }

    // Present the scene.
    [_yourSKView presentScene:LoaderScreen];


}
```

2) now second solution and best solution (quality wise) is that go two textures atlas where first texture atlas follow iPad series ratio and second 5 and 6 series because 5 and 6 follow same aspect ratio so you don't need to worry but for 4s squashed little SKScene (that can't be fixed without three texture atlas)

Answer (score 0):

It is all about the Aspect Ratio for the different models. 
Luckily there only two for `iOS` devices 4:3 or 16:9. This would be much harder for android devices as there are more different aspect ratio's.

Check here for info on that :
[iOS Device Resolution](http://www.iosres.com/)

You could take the highest res images for each aspect ratio and use texturepacker to do the scaling.
This will cost some money but it's worth it.(not affiliated with the company).

Or checkout the free android stuff!:

[Android Asset Studio](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html)